# Text without use of amsmath

Tags: displaystyle

Is it possible to write text within math display environment without using the amsmath package ?

Have seen the use of `\text{something}` but the command is from `amsmath`.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! Is there a reason why you're unable to use the `amsmath` package?

Comment: I want to make my own library without relying on `amsmath`.

Comment: `amsmath` relies on another package known as `amstext` to provide the `\text` command. If you want `\text` without importing the rest of AMS Math, perhaps you could use `\RequirePackage{amstext}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the `\textXX` formatting commands (`\textrm`, `\textit`, etc.) to switch to text mode. The `\text` command from `amsmath` will get the surrounding formatting (e.g., in a theorem, it would print the text in italics), but I think that this is rarely, if ever, desirable.

The other thing that `amsmath` gives you which is harder to replicate is that it automatically makes all of these commands adjust size if they appear in super- or subscripts, so, for example, you could write `$e^{\textrm{really big number}}$` and get the expected size adjustment. That said, in most instances, you probably really want to do something like `$n_{\mathrm{something}}$` since text mode is only necessary if you have spaces in your text and multi-word sub- and super-scripts are uncommon.